# upgrade artifactory to 7.71.11 from: 7.63.14 failed

Tags: linux, debian, artifactory

I tried to upgrade Artifactory to 7.71.11 from: 7.63.14 on Debian 11 and running it on LXC container on proxmox,

upgrade process passed successfully and the service started but cannot login to the forntend login page and find many warnings in the console logs,

I get a sample logs here, can you advice what is the wrong with the upgrade

```
024-01-21T07:37:32.216Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [116426b736727563] [healthcheck.go:62             ] [main                ] [] - Checking health of service 'jfob_01czdtt9fz9mz703afdvy011nf-af-upgrade' using URL 'http://localhost:8036/api/v1/system/readiness' returned an error: Get "http://localhost:8036/api/v1/system/readiness": dial tcp [::1]:8036: connect: connection refused
2024-01-21T07:37:32.216Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [116426b736727563] [healthcheck.go:62             ] [main                ] [] - Checking health of service 'jffe_01gg7b0vkvvyd110xvkc2w1ajr-af-upgrade' using URL 'http://localhost:8070/readiness' returned an error: Get "http://localhost:8070/readiness": dial tcp [::1]:8070: connect: connection refused
2024-01-21T07:37:32.222Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [116426b736727563] [local_topology_helper.go:68   ] [main                ] [] - Missing required services: [jfrt]
2024-01-21T07:37:32.222Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [116426b736727563] [local_topology.go:367         ] [main                ] [] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"
```

restart the serive and try to change the port 8070 to 8071 but it still the same

Comment: It looks like artifactory process was not started right. router logs are not helping in this case but artifactory-service.log will reveal more about why the service is not starting.
Please share the error there and I might be able to assist.